# парс json через тэг script src

Tags: javascript, html

у меня есть js на домене. example.com/user.js
Как мне получить из нее данные через script?

```
<script src=example.com/user.js>parse.json.data</script>
```

Comment: Как в `.js` файл можно положить `.json` формат?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете искать элемент либо по `id` заранее ему проставив, либо по тегу `script`, в этом случае необходимо знать сколько скриптов у Вас в документе.
В данном случае получает src первого элемента с тегом `script`. `[0]`

```js
    let script = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].src;
    console.log(script);
```

```html
<script src=example.com/user.js>parse.json.data</script>
```